# BC30203: Identifier expected VS2010 and 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm getting an `BC30203: Identifier expected` error in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I have zero idea why this is happening and I'm getting extremely frustrated. I have no idea where the error is (besides the class).

I hadn't even touched the page for days (last time it was working) and now I get the error. Clearing temp files, .NET Framework temp files don't help either, restarting, reinstalling VS. I even switched from 2010 to 2012RC with no luck. I'm at a complete loss.

I've removed more and more code and it seems to happen whenever I declare a variable. It is not my models or anything else as they work 100%, just not in this one page.

Here is the code from the partial view:

```
@ModelType Frontend.Models.Collection 

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "GetFilters"
End Code

@AddSeparator("Options")
@Options

@Helper Options()   

    Dim less As String=String.Empty
    @<div class="ui-splitbutton filter">
        <a class="@less" href="#" title="Show only basic filters" rel="nofollow">Show less</a>
        <a class="" href="#" title="Show all available filters" rel="nofollow">Show more</a> 
    </div>

    @<div>
        <a class="button clear_filters filter" href="#" title="Remove all applied filters" rel="nofollow">Clear filters</a>
     </div>

End Helper

@Helper AddSeparator(text As String)                                               
    @<div class="separator">
        <span>@text</span>
    </div>
End Helper
```

Here is how I render the page:

```
@Code
    Html.RenderPartial("_PartialFilters", Model)
End code
```

And here is the exception:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3a7646ef\5efed268\App_Web__partialfilters.vbhtml.34d3db15.w7n2unx9.0.vb(60): error BC30203: Identifier expected.
  Source=System.Web
  SourceCode=#ExternalChecksum("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml","{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}","EE63B19A6BCF554D9625D51B8F673B27C85CCC09")
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17626
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Helpers
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
Imports System.Web.Mvc.Html
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.WebPages

Namespace ASP

    Public Class _Page_Views_Browse__PartialFilters_vbhtml
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage(Of Frontend.Models.Collection)


#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 10)
Public Function Options() As System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult

#End ExternalSource
Return New System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(Sub (__razor_helper_writer)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 10)


    Dim less As String=String.Empty

#End ExternalSource
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 202, 4, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "    ")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 202, 4, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 207, 4, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "<div")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 207, 4, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 211, 30, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " class=""ui-splitbutton filter""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 211, 30, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 241, 13, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, ">"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"        <a")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 241, 13, true)
WriteAttributeTo(__razor_helper_writer, "class", Tuple.Create(" class=""", 254), Tuple.Create("""", 267) _, Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("", 262), Tuple.Create(Of System.Object, System.Int32)(less _, 262), False) _)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 268, 9, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " href=""#""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 268, 9, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 277, 32, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " title=""Show only basic filters""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 277, 32, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 309, 15, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " rel=""nofollow""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 309, 15, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 324, 26, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, ">Show less</a>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"        <a")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 324, 26, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 350, 9, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " class=""""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 350, 9, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 359, 9, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " href=""#""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 359, 9, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 368, 35, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " title=""Show all available filters""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 368, 35, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 403, 15, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " rel=""nofollow""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 403, 15, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 418, 29, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, ">Show more</a> "&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"    </div>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 418, 29, true)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 17)


#End ExternalSource
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 449, 4, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "    ")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 449, 4, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 454, 17, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "<div>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"        <a")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 454, 17, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 471, 36, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " class=""button clear_filters filter""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 471, 36, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 507, 9, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " href=""#""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 507, 9, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 516, 35, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " title=""Remove all applied filters""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 516, 35, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 551, 15, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " rel=""nofollow""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 551, 15, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 566, 33, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, ">Clear filters</a>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"     </div>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 566, 33, true)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 21)


#End ExternalSource
End Sub)
End Function


#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 24)
Public Function AddSeparator(text As String) As System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult

#End ExternalSource
Return New System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(Sub (__razor_helper_writer)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 24)


#End ExternalSource
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 727, 4, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "    ")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 727, 4, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 732, 4, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "<div")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 732, 4, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 736, 18, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, " class=""separator""")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 736, 18, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 754, 17, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, ">"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"        <span>")
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 754, 17, true)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 772, 4, false)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 26)
WriteTo(__razor_helper_writer, text)

#End ExternalSource
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 772, 4, false)
BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 776, 21, true)
WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "</span>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&"    </div>"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))
EndContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 776, 21, true)

#ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 28)

#End ExternalSource
End Sub)
End Function


        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
        End Sub

        Protected ReadOnly Property ApplicationInstance() As ASP.global_asax
            Get
                Return CType(Context.ApplicationInstance,ASP.global_asax)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub Execute()
BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 40, 2, true)

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))

EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 40, 2, true)


            #ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml",3)

    ViewData("Title") = "GetFilters"


            #End ExternalSource
BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 95, 4, true)

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))

EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 95, 4, true)

BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 100, 23, false)


            #ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml",7)
Write(AddSeparator("Options"))


            #End ExternalSource
EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 100, 23, false)

BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 123, 2, true)

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))

EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 123, 2, true)

BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 126, 7, false)


            #ExternalSource("C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\_PartialFilters.vbhtml",8)
Write(Options)


            #End ExternalSource
EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 126, 7, false)

BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 133, 4, true)

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))

EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 133, 4, true)

BeginContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 638, 4, true)

WriteLiteral(""&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10))

EndContext("~/Views/Browse/_PartialFilters.vbhtml", 638, 4, true)

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetPathFromGeneralName>b__0(String path)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath>b__8(IDisplayMode mode)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode, Boolean requireConsistentDisplayMode)
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass8.<FindPartialView>b__7(IViewEngine e)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
       at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext, String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
       at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
       at ASP._Page_Views_Browse_Index_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\Users\Amy Pond\Documents\ilovetv\Code\Store\Frontend\Views\Browse\Index.vbhtml:line 16
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who this happens to and cannot fix...

For me, inside the partial page I was creating a lot of dropdowns and other controls. I made a helper for this and moved the bulk of the code to a @Function helper and use the TagBuilder.

I don't think it is a cheap workaround - too much. I still don't have any idea of the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I had a simple page without this line because I didn't want the site master. When I put it in it was ok.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```